# VB - Divide integers doesn't include commas?

Tags: vba, excel, integer, divide

This is probably an easy one, but I've got this Excel vba macro where I'm trying to divide two integers and I end up with a round number, even though there should be a comma in there. 
For example 278 / 101 = 3. While it's really 2,75 and not 3. Why is this?

The macro is really simple, like this:

```
Dim intFull, intLow , intDivided as Integer
intFull = 278
intLow = 101
intDivided = intFull \ intLow
```

Comment: can we see the macro? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your result variables is an **integer**

If you work with **doubles** instead you will get 2.752 etc - which can be rounded using `dbDivided = Round(lngFull / lngLow, 2)`

[variables updated to be more meaningful]

```
Sub redone()
    Dim lngFull As Long
    Dim lngLow As Long
    Dim dbDivided As Double
    lngFull = 278
    lngLow = 101
    dbDivided = Round(lngFull / lngLow, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: And that was it! Thanks! I should have guessed this really.. Something tells me this is pretty basic Visual Basic :) Thanx!

Comment: `Dim intFull As Integer, intLow As Integer, dblDivided As Double` works correctly. Unlike, for example, Java (where `int/int` produces an `int` result,) `Integer/Integer` does not always produce an `Integer` result in VBA - it depends on the type of variable that the result is assigned to. Also, `Dim intFull, intLow, intDivided As Double` gives us two `Variant` variables and one `Double` variable. Finally, a `Double` variable with a name prepended with `int` is just going to lead to confusion

Comment: @barrowc. Agree on naming convention and have updated accordingly, Long being more efficient than Integer. Also have updated the variants which while workable is untidy, I should have run my standard single line dimensioning style. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you used a forward slash and not a backslash? (See also: http://zo-d.com/blog/archives/programming/vba-integer-division-and-mod.html)

Comment: Hmm, I've tried both / and \ now. When I use /, I get a value of 3. When I use \ I get a value of 2.

Comment: see above. The main issue was your variable type. The secondary issues was the backslash which Joachim identified. Both are fixed in my post

Comment: +1 for posting first on the backslash remainder discard issue.